# Datastax mapper complains about duplicate columns in generated insert statement

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

Versions: Datastax Java driver 3.1.4, Cassandra 3.10

Consider the following table:

```
create table object_ta
(
  objid         bigint,
  version_date  timestamp,
  objecttype    ascii,
  primary key  (objid, version_date)
);
```

And a mapped class:

```
@Table(name = "object_ta")
public class ObjectTa
{
    @Column(name = "objid")
    private long objid;
    @Column(name = "version_date")
    private Instant versionDate;
    @Column(name = "objecttype")
    private String objectType;

    public ObjectTa()
    {
    }

    public ObjectTa(long objid)
    {
        this.objid = objid;
        this.versionDate = Instant.now();
    }

    public long getObjId()
    {
        return objid;
    }

    public void setObjId(long objid)
    {
        this.objid = objid;
    }

    public Instant getVersionDate()
    {
        return versionDate;
    }

    public void setVersionDate(Instant versionDate)
    {
        this.versionDate = versionDate;
    }

    public String getObjectType()
    {
        return objectType;
    }

    public void setObjectType(String objectType)
    {
        this.objectType = objectType;
    }
}
```

After creating a mapper for this class (`mm` is a `MappingManager` for the session on *mykeyspace*)

```
final Mapper<ObjectTa> mapper = mm.mapper(ObjectTa.class);
```

On calling

```
mapper.save(new ObjectTa(1));
```

I get

> Query preparation failed: INSERT INTO mykeyspace.object_ta
>   (objid,objid,version_date,objecttype) VALUES (?,?,?,?);:
>   com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: The column
>   names contains duplicates     at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:136)
>     at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$4.apply(SessionManager.java:220)
>     at
>   com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager$4.apply(SessionManager.java:196)
>     at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$ChainingListenableFuture.run(Futures.java:906)
>     at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$1$1.run(Futures.java:635)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I am at a loss to understand, why the duplicate `objid` is generated in the query.

Thank you in advance for pointers to the problem.

Clemens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because the inconsistent use of case on the field name (`objid`) vs the setter/getters (`getObjId`).  If you rename `getObjId` and `setObjId` to `getObjid` and `setObjid` respectively, I believe it might work.

In a future release, the driver mapper will allow the user to be more explicit about whether setters/getters are used ([JAVA-1310](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-1310)) and what the naming conventions are ([JAVA-1316](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-1316)).

Comment: This helped, after renaming the getter and setter to match the case as you suggested, it works. Thank you very much!